Let $0 < v_1<\dots< v_n$ and $0 < x_i \in \{N_1, ..., N_n\}$. How to max/min $\sum x_i v_i $?
Let $0 < v_1 < \dots< v_n$ with $v_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x_i \in \{N_1, ..., N_n\}$ with all $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$. If I want to maximize (and minimize the sum)
$$
\min\sum_{i=1}^n v_i x_i \hspace{1cm} \max \sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i.
$$ How should I choose the $x_i$? Is there a known algorithm for this?
Work so far
Assume $N_1 < \ldots < N_n$. Then for maximization, is the solution $v_n \cdot N_n + \ldots + v_1 \cdot N_1$ respectively $v_1 \cdot N_n + \ldots + v_n \cdot N_1$ for minimization? I think that somehow the knapsack problem can be adapted to this ...

See rearrangement inequality.

@MartinR that is exactly what I was looking for

@MartinR: Thanks for the reference. I didn't realise it had a name.

Let $0<v_1<\ldots<v_n$ and $0<N_1<\ldots<N_n$, and $x_i=N_{\sigma_i}$ for some permutation $\sigma$.
If $j<k$ and $p<q$, then
$$
0<(v_k-v_j)(N_q-N_p)=(v_jN_p+v_kN_q)-(v_jN_q+v_kN_p)
$$
which makes $v_jN_p+v_kN_q>v_jN_q+v_kN_p$.
For the sum $\sum v_ix_i$ this means that if for some $j<k$ we have $x_j>x_k$, we can make the sum bigger by swapping $x_j$ and $x_k$; conversely, if $x_j<x_k$, we can make the sum smaller by swapping $x_j$ and $x_k$.
So, for the permutation that maximises the sum, there can be no $x_j>x_k$ for $j<k$, which means it must be in increasing order. Conversely, for the minimum, there can be no $x_j<x_k$, so it must be in decreasing order.

Thank you for this nice proof of the "rearrangement inequality" (as I have just learned that this problem is called)
